# Spring where I should connect to my MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring

I want to connect to my database (MongoDB) but I don't know what file is responsible for this.

My [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPARl.png)

In which file can I stuff it?

```
ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("<DATABASE URL>");
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
        .serverApi(ServerApi.builder()
            .version(ServerApiVersion.V1)
            .build())
        .build();
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to [install](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/2.7.0) MongoDB Spring Boot dependency

Then in your application.properties you need to put MongoDB URI like that: spring.data.mongodb.uri = [URI]

On your project structure i can see UserRepository, it should look similar to this:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<UserEntity, String> {

}
```

And now you can use your UserRepository everywhere just by using
`@Autowired UserRepository userRepository`